# What does it mean by <provided> with <exclusion>?

Tags: java, maven

Let's consider this example

```
        <groupId>com.abc.3rdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-gsb-scala</artifactId>
        <version>${GsbScalaVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.abc.3rdparty</groupId>
                <artifactId>safebrowsing2_2.9.1-0.2.5.jar</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

As I understand, `<provided>` means that the container will provide the jar right?

so what does `<exclusion>` means? that one of the `jar` within that will be provided by the project/application?

I am confused

Comment: I believe maven resolves transitive dependencies. So if you include `A` and it has a dependency on `B`, maven will pull in `B` as well. You can prevent that with exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your build, your hunch is correct, the exclusion won't do anything because it will be left out anyway. But if you're using an IDE that pulls in dependencies for you, this will exclude those transient dependencies while you develop. Make sense?

Comment: I should add that `Provided` dependencies aren't on the final build by default, but they ARE present during compilation and runtime. Your exclude clause prevents them from appearing on the classpath during compilation and runtime.